# Creating study indicators using multiple conditions

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading

I am trying to create a study(not a strategy) that will indicate when to buy and sell given the satisfaction of different sets of conditions.

In this code, I want to be able to distinguish what kind of trade that I am in. So if I initiate a trade with longCond1, only shortCond1 will be able to indicate an exit. Autoview had a suggestion about using the crossover function to indicate this, but it was only using 1 condition not 2.

```
longCond1 = close>open[1] ? 1:0
shortCond1 = open<close[1] ? 1:0

longCond2 = close>high[1] ? 1:0
shortCond2 = close>high[2] ? 1:0


plot(longCond1)
plot(shortCond1)
plot(longCond2)
plot(shortCond2)
```

Answer (score 1):

I've created an example script that should help you. https://www.tradingview.com/script/llcoIPKG-Pine-Example-Holding-a-state-in-a-variable/

```
//@version=3
study("Holding a state in a variable")
longCond1 = close>open[1] // Just some entry signal (GREEN)
shortCond1 = open<close[1] // Just some exit signal (RED)
isInPosition = false // Variable that holds some state (BLACK)
isInPosition := na(isInPosition[1]) ? false : isInPosition[1]

if longCond1 and not isInPosition
    isInPosition := true

if shortCond1 and isInPosition
    isInPosition := false

plot(isInPosition ? 3 : na, color=black, linewidth=2, style=linebr)
plot(shortCond1 ? 2 : na, color=red, style=linebr)
plot(longCond1 ? 1 : na, color=green, style=linebr)
```

NOTE: There is a Pine Script version 4 is coming, it will be much easier with it's new feature 'var' keyword, [read more](https://docs.google.com/document/d/12ogvjzasBJSXerSOql4b9KwkE3wUlsc5HgA5qGhoYXk/edit#heading=h.v9agvnik34tl).